# Parse unable to add cloudcode to existing app

Tags: parse-platform

Getting

> You are not a collaborator on app: 1

when trying to add my local cloud code to an app via `parse add`.

I am able to deploy to all the apps because I have a account key. Apparently I am not a collaborator on my own apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding yourself as a collaborator? In the parse dashboard:

```
 <your app> -> App Settings -> General -> Collaborators
```

Comment: I can't since I own the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the problem was that I was typing the number it listed for the project instead of the whole name. /facepalm.

1:      Android6-BETA
2:      Android6-PROD
3:      Android6-QA
4:      Android6
5:      iOS6-BETA
6:      iOS6-PROD
7:      iOS6-QA

i.e. parse add 1